# remove with jquery not in parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

How to remove all `<li>` tags `( ul.gallery li )` when click on the `<button>`.
The Button is outside the `<ul>`.

```
<div class="gallery">
  <ul class="gallery-list">
    <li>
        <img src="sample">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="sample">           
    </li>
    <li>    
        <img src="sample">            
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class="button"></button>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('.button').on( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parents( '.gallery li' ).animate( { opacity: 0 }, 300,function() {
        jQuery(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should show your attempts here first.

Comment: And probably ask a more specific question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: jQuery('.button').on( 'click', function( e ) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
 
  jQuery(this).parents( '.gallery li' ).animate( { opacity: 0 }, 300, function() {
  
   jQuery(this).remove();

  });

Comment: Use `jQuery(this).parents().find( '.gallery li' ).animate(...`

Comment: @ Mohammad thank you. this works !

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
jQuery('.button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.gallery .gallery-list li').remove(); 
});
```

or like this according to your code :

```
jQuery('.button').on( 'click', function( e ) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var gallery = jQuery(this).parents( '.gallery' );

    jQuery(gallery).animate( { opacity: 0 }, 300, function() {

        jQuery(".gallery-list li", jQuery(gallery)).remove(); 

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are looking for removing all the `li` elements under the class `gallery-list`. You can try as below -

```
jQuery('.button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.gallery-list > li').animate({
    opacity: 0
        }, 300, function() {
        jQuery(this).remove();
    });

});
```